# Postgresql Streaming Replication - pgpool2 - failover

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1, failover, pgpool

In my scenario I want pgpool to forward read only queries to slaves when the master goes down - I want my app to be in the "read only mode".

How do I setup pgpool to accept read only queries when master fails (streaming replication) ?

Currently I when the master goes down, pgpool waits for the master and doesn't forward any queries to slaves.

Comment: I suspect you'll need to switch to routing read/write vs read-only queries at the application level to do this.